# Orientation on JavaCameraView and android (OpenCV)

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm a new developer in openCV API, I can't set the orientation on JavaCameraView, can someone help with the code?

The orientation on the camera seems inverted.

The axis too is inverted, already tried the function setMaxFrameSize(), but no success.

```
public class AbrirCamera extends Activity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2 {

    private JavaCameraView mOpencvCameraView;

    private OrientationEventListener orientationListener = null;



    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch(status)
            {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                    Log.i(TAG, "Sucesso Carregando OpenCV.");
                    mOpencvCameraView.enableView();
                    break;

                default:
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                    break;

            }
        }
    };


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_abrir_camera);

        mOpencvCameraView = (JavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.aCameraView);
        mOpencvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
        mOpencvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
        mOpencvCameraView.enableFpsMeter();


    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_6, this, mLoaderCallback);
    }

    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mOpencvCameraView != null)
        {
            mOpencvCameraView.disableView();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {



    }


    @Override
    public void onCameraViewStopped() {

    }

    @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {


        return inputFrame.rgba();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i came up with the answer myself,

just added the file styles.xml like this:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="Landscape_camera">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

after that just modified the layout in the activity for using this style.